# Copy selection range from sheet and open outlook and paste the copied content in a new email

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone tell me what type of BodyFormat I need to put (olFormat...)
and how to declare
a=Range("A1:G" & r).Copy
and then what to put in body of the e-mail

I don't want it to copy it as HTML.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my code

```
Sub Button()
 Dim str As String
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Dim EmailBodyTotal As String
 name_work = ActiveSheet.Name
 daytime = Right(name_work, 2)
 With OutMail
   .To = ""
   .cc = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "" 
    .Body = Range("A1:G" & r )
    .Display
 End With

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will generate a plain-text email with your cell reference as the email body and display the email message window.  You can skip that part, and un-comment the .send line; that will directly send your email.

```
Sub sendMail()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strEmailTo As String
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 'as appropriate
olNs.Logon
strEmailTo = "" 'insert email address(es) here
With olMail
    .To = strEmailTo
    .subject = ""   'email subject goes here
    .Body = Range("A1:G" & r)   'or put the values in a string variable
    .Display
   '.Send
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it like that, but I get the same error when I put the values in a string variable..
"Run-time error 440
Object does not support this method."
on the line .Body=Range("A1:G" & r)

Comment: @user2472368 try changing the line to `Set .Body = Range("A1:G" & r)`

Comment: Run-time error 1004-Method Range of object '_Global' failed after I do that.

I edited my question-added the whole code (it is almost identical to this first solution)

Comment: So nobody knows the solution? Another question is, if I actually manage to copy the range programatically, when I paste would the content look like the Excel file? Because when I copy and paste manually to the email, formatting gets copied too